# Weight and score data from 3 columns dataframe pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

my question is about scoring.

i have a dataset contains 6 columns customerID, DetailsAccess , Category, max, min, count_details, total_duration, Total_volume. i want to calculate a weight or score with this three columns : (count_details, total_duration, total_volume) , how i do to define function for scoring  the usage data for user. i need to give a weight for usage by user.

Thank u :)

```
Customer_ID;Details;Category;maxx;minn;Count_DETAILS;Total_Duration(s);total_Volume(byte);Weight (Score)
1;AA;A;436.0;436.0;1;322.0;436.0;?
2;AA;A;413.0;413.0;1;559.0;413.0;?
3;AA;A;378.0;378.0;1;579.0;378.0;?
1;DDD;C;2.0;2.0;1;1.0;2.0;?
3;CCC;A;80.0;80.0;1;277.0;80.0;?
4;BB;B;4.0;4.0;1;498.0;4.0;?
5;AA;A;16.0;16.0;1;483.0;16.0;?
6;AA;A;860.0;860.0;1;599.0;860.0;?
```

[image]

i need to create this output :

```
custumer_id/Details;    Score_AA;   Score_BB;   Score_CCC;  Score_DDD
1;  score;  score;  score;  score
2;  score;  score;  score;  score
3;  score;  score;  score;  score
4;  score;  score;  score;  score
5;  score;  score;  score;  score
6;  score;  score;  score;  score
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmQqp.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [mcve]. In this example, do provide your existing code attempting to manipulate the data. In addition, define precisely your required output.

Comment: usage for user is total of sum usage this data is an aggregation for details data

Customer_ID;Details;Category;maxx;minn;Count_DETAILS;Total_Duration(s);total_Volume(byte);Weight (Score)
1;AA;A;436.0;436.0;1;322.0;436.0;?
2;AA;A;413.0;413.0;1;559.0;413.0;?
3;AA;A;378.0;378.0;1;579.0;378.0;?
1;DDD;C;2.0;2.0;1;1.0;2.0;?
3;CCC;A;80.0;80.0;1;277.0;80.0;?
4;BB;B;4.0;4.0;1;498.0;4.0;?
5;AA;A;16.0;16.0;1;483.0;16.0;?
6;AA;A;860.0;860.0;1;599.0;860.0;?

Comment: Customer_ID;Details;Category;maxx;minn;Count_DETAILS;Total_Duration(s);total_Volume(byte);Weight (Score)
1;AA;A;436.0;436.0;1;322.0;436.0;?
2;AA;A;413.0;413.0;1;559.0;413.0;?
3;AA;A;378.0;378.0;1;579.0;378.0;?
1;DDD;C;2.0;2.0;1;1.0;2.0;?
3;CCC;A;80.0;80.0;1;277.0;80.0;?
4;BB;B;4.0;4.0;1;498.0;4.0;?
5;AA;A;16.0;16.0;1;483.0;16.0;?
6;AA;A;860.0;860.0;1;599.0;860.0;?

Comment: my output is a pivot table contain 

custumer_id/Details; Score_AA; Score_BB; Score_CCC; Score_DDD
1; score; score; score; score
2; score; score; score; score
3; score; score; score; score
4; score; score; score; score
5; score; score; score; score
6; score; score; score; score

Comment: @EspoirMurhabazi i have added the input and output in question:)

Comment: How is the score calculated ?

Comment: i try to create function for calculate a scrore ! i can't do this ! how i can calculate a score or weight from volume of data usage and count with duration?

Comment: How will you going to combine them ?? Volume/weight ???

Comment: maybe volume with count for calculate scorring

Comment: I found this library weightedcalcs , but I do not know if it calculates the weight well

Comment: Send a link to the lib please

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/weightedcalcs